# Calculate new coordinate after image gets rotated by certain degree

Tags: android, opencv

[image][image]

Hi Guys,

I am new here for Android. I am working extensively on one App which capture the images edges and manipulate it. I am drawing a Ploygon kind of shape on the top of my image after its captured with coordinates I got from Open CV. All things are working fine unless I rotate it. When I do rotate, i also want the move the drawn coordinates as per shown in the image. If I rotate to 90 degree then I need to calculate coordinates according to new degree and draw the border accordingly. I have the center of all cooordinates of first screen shot. Below is the code for the same:

```
private PointF getCenter(HashMap<Integer, PointF> points){
    PointF centerPoint = new PointF();
    int size = points.size();
    for(Integer i : points.keySet()){
        PointF p = points.get(i);
        centerPoint.x += p.x / size;
        centerPoint.y += p.y / size;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, " centerPoint.x "+centerPoint.x);
    Log.d(TAG, " centerPoint.y "+centerPoint.y);
    return centerPoint;
}
```

But I am stuck here of how to calculate the new coordinates of rotated image. I am bad at mathematics as well. Please help me. I am rotating it with 90 degree.

The first image I am getting from OpenCV and second I want to achieve.

Regards,
Munish

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply your coordinates by the rotation matrix R (which obviously depends on the angle):

```
new_coords = R*old_coords
```

I think it is [already implemented](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) in OpenCV, but you can easily write R [by your self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Comment: Hi Carlos,

Below is the code I am using to rotate matrix:

Matrix matrix =  new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(getDegree());
            Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    matrix, true);

I know the degree (it can be 90 degree or any other). I have old coordinates which you can see in picture. I have eight coordinates (x1y1, x2y2, x3y3, x4y4).
You want me to multiply these with angle?

Comment: Can you help me of how to calculate rotation matrix if its rotated by 90 degree. I am bad in mathematics.

Comment: If you have 8 points then you must apply what I said 8 times. `new_x1 = cos(theta)*old_x1 - sin(theta)*old_y1` ; `new_y1 = sin(theta)*old_x1 + cos(theta)*old_y1` and so on. It is very well explained in Wikipedia in the "In two dimensions" section. If this helped you, please mark the answer as correct

Comment: HI Carlos,
As per you said I have applied the formula :

x0 = (float)  ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) * point0.x) - (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) * point0.y)) ;
                y0 = (float)  ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90)) * point0.x) + (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)) * point0.y)) ;

I did for the rest of the coordinates, but I am not gettin the output.

Am I doing anything wrong. PLease help

Comment: Old Coordinates:
{1=PointF(663.0, 245.0), 0=PointF(96.0, 339.0), 3=PointF(641.0, 625.0), 2=PointF(87.0, 588.0)}

New after 90 degree rotation:
{1=PointF(-245.0, 663.0), 0=PointF(-339.0, 96.0), 3=PointF(-625.0, 641.0), 2=PointF(-588.0, 87.0)}

Comment: HCarlos,

I am doing 90 degree Clockwise. still this would be the formula right which you suggested?

Comment: Finally I found the solution of this. I have maintained the image width and height and after every rotation I am subtracting the coordinates from that. It gives me perfect result.

Comment: So after rotation, you are using the above formula to get new coordinates and then subtract new coordinates with bitmap height & Width? @Munish